# Ubuntu 14.04 can't find files

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I am using Codeigniter 3 and setup a virtualbox using Puphpet. I am usgin Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache2. I have finally successfully been able to access my default controller route when I go to http://ip_address/, but when I try to access another page it says Not Found.

I have my shared folder mounted to /var/www. I have also verified that all of my files are located here.

Any idea why the default controller loads, but says not found for the other pages?

EDIT: the .htaccess file is located in the root folder (/var/www) this is the contents of the .htaccess file:

```
# MAKE SURE TO LEAVE THE NEXT TWO LINES HERE.
# BEGIN DENY LIST --
# END DENY LIST --

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
AllowOveride All
```

I have also made changes to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/10-default_vhost_80.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/25-av_fv5lzxiyh2xc.conf`

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted   

    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
      Require all granted
      SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
    </FilesMatch>

  </Directory>dexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
```

UPDATE: If I enter my url like `http://ip_address/index.php/login` the page is found if I enter my url like `http://ip_address/login` the page is not found.

Comment: Can you access to other pages leaving `index.php` in url?

Comment: yes, if I leave index.php in the url i am able to access the other pages.

Comment: Try with adding qsa question mark like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Although I didn't make some settings to FilesMatch in apache recently, do you have all modules enabled, proxy, fcgi etc?

Comment: sorry i'm a bit new at this. how do I check?

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/284898/how-to-check-which-apache-modules-are-enabled-installed).

Comment: Thanks. should I list the modules in my question? I do not see the ones you mentioned - proxy, fcgi, etc.

Comment: I am not sure which one need to be enabled. Probably `mod_proxy_fcgi`. Somebody else should answer that or you can search on google or somewhere for that. [Docs here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by editing the default config file here:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

And I added this to the default config:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All   
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```